# Do desktop environments have xorg dependencies?

Tags: debian, xorg, dependencies

I have installed Debian 9 with no GUI.

Now, I wanted to install a desktop environment. To do that I've just used:

```
sudo apt install mate-desktop-environment-extras
```

I've assumed that, since a desktop environment depends on a graphic environment in order to work, it will have some xorg dependencies and that it should install it automatically. However it appears that it's not the case, since when using `startx` nothing happens and `apt list | grep xorg` shows that no xorg related package is installed.

Could somebody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: Package dependencies are decided by package maintainer, not by software code. And if you have `startx` command, something will happen. If you don't, something else will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mate-desktop-environment-extras` doesn’t end up depending on X.org, as you’ve discovered.

The way you’re supposed to install a desktop environment, starting from scratch, is with `tasksel`, or the corresponding `task-` package, `task-mate-desktop` in this case. This is how the installer provisions the chosen desktop. (This is documented, albeit cryptically, in [the Debian Reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch07.en.html#_key_packages).)

At least in MATE and GNOME’s cases, I think this is because the non-task meta-packages are intended to pull in the packages corresponding to the official software produced by the projects involved, and X.org isn’t part of that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.